# How to start `redis-sentinel` server successfully

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel, redis-server

Sorry redis newbie here.

When I run `redis-sentinel`

```
42533:X 10 Nov 21:21:30.345 # Warning: no config file specified, using 
the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis- 
sentinel /path/to/sentinel.conf
42533:X 10 Nov 21:21:30.346 * Increased maximum number of open files to 
10032 (it was originally set to 7168).
Redis 3.0.4 (00000000/0) 64 bit

Running in sentinel mode
Port: 26379
PID: 42533
http://redis.io

42533:X 10 Nov 21:21:30.347 # Sentinel runid is 
733213860cf470431c7441e5d6aaf9ed9b2d7c2f
42533:X 10 Nov 21:21:30.347 # Sentinel started without a config file. 
Exiting...
```

What am I missing? Do I need a configuration file? If so where should my `/path/to/sentinel.conf` be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is mandatory to use a configuration file when running Sentinel, as this file will be used by the system in order to save the current state that will be reloaded in case of restarts. Sentinel will simply refuse to start if no configuration file is given or if the configuration file path is not writable.

you can run Sentinel with the following command line:

```
redis-sentinel /path/to/sentinel.conf
```

Otherwise you can use directly the redis-server executable starting it in Sentinel mode:

```
redis-server /path/to/sentinel.conf --sentinel
```

You can put the file anywhere you want, just make sure you are providing the right path for that. For example, if you are in linux and if the file is inside your home directory, then the command will be

```
redis-sentinel ~/sentinel.conf
```

Comment: Awesome thanks. I was able to do that with the following result, does everything look ok?

    # Sentinel
    sentinel_masters:1
    sentinel_tilt:0
    sentinel_running_scripts:0
    sentinel_scripts_queue_length:0
master0:name=mymaster,status=odown,address=127.0.0.1:6666,slaves=2,sentinels=1

Is  Status = odown correct? I am still getting No sentinels available. (Redis::CannotConnectError) from my rails application but that might be because my config in rails is wrong

Comment: what if i wanted sentinel to start on system bootup @monzurul